# How to Setup Resolution and Frame Rate Between Two Cameras for Premiere Editting and YouTube

Tags: video, video-quality, dslr, canon, framerate

I have a Canon Vixia HF G10 and a Canon 70D. I need to do an interview requiring two camera angles. I need to figure out what the best way to ensure both cameras record video at the highest frame rate, resolution etc but match so that I don't have a post production nightmare on my hands.

Canon Vixia HF G10 does 60i, PF30 and PF24 (recorded as 60i) and 24P. It appears the resolution is determined by video quality (either 1920x1080 or 1440x1080). I have been using MXP mode (1920x1080 - 24MBits) on PF30 for the past year with decent results.

Canon 70D does either 1920x1080 @ 30 or 24 or 1280x720 @ 60 (I am guessing progressive, but the manual does not confirm this). I will of course record in their better compression method ALL-I. I currently am testing the 70D @ 1920x1080 24 ALL-I and it appears to be ok.

All post is preferred to rely on stock Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 if possible and the final result will be published on YouTube for sure and may be played off a Windows PC inside the client's office. I am not really picky about 30p or 24p.

I would appreciate an expert's opinion on the best way to set this up so I don't end up with two different frame rates, crappy results or wasting time in post editing because I screwed it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1080P/24 seems to be the way to go in this case.  It's generally considered to have a more cinematic look and both cameras appear to support that resolution and framerate.  Youtube has a 24 fps setting and should handle 1080P video fine.  As you already said, use All I on your 70D to ensure highest quality.